# computed property in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "value": 4,
    "text": "All Belgium Kendo Federation"
  },
  {
    "value": 33,
    "text": "All United States Kendo Federation"
  },
  // more objects of similar key/value
]
```

I want to create a computed property with the id as parameter, so I can get text with value.

So, I try:

```
computed: {
        federationSelectedText: function () {

            this.federations.find(function (elt) {
                return elt.value == this.federationSelected;
            });
        }
    },
```

Where `this.federationSelect` is the value.

And in HTML `{{ federationSelectedText }}`

I debugged variables, and both `this.federations` and `this.federationSelected` have correct value

It doesn't display nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `elt ` in the computed function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need return `value` and bind `this` for `find`

```
computed: {
        federationSelectedText: function () {

            return this.federations.find(function (elt) {
                return elt.value == this.federationSelected;
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
```

For get one variable:

```
computed: {
            federationSelectedText: function () {

                var value = this.federations.find(function (elt) {
                    return elt.value == this.federationSelected;
                }.bind(this));

                return value ? value.text : '';
            }
        }
```

Comment: It worked. Should I always use bind() in computed properties?

Comment: No. It depends by use case. When you are using `function` in `map`,`filter`,... meaning of `this` is changing. Try checking meaning of `this` in javascript.

Comment: how should I do to get text attribute? I seems easy but couldn t do it :8

Comment: You rock! Thanks for your great help!